# overwrite whole year in case of missing data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I would like to manipulate a dataframe and fill it with NaN depending on a special condition: As soon as there is a value missing in a year, I want the whole year to be filled with NaN values. So lets suppose my dataframe looks like this and I am working with a datetime index:

```
           Score    
2005-12-29 NaN  
2005-12-30 NaN  
2005-12-31 20.3     
2006-01-02 30.9     
2006-01-02 14.9     
2006-01-03 14.1     
...
2006-12-31 14.8     
2007-01-01 14.7     
2007-01-02 NaN
```

Now I would like to write a code which detects that in 2005 and 2007 there are values missing, and therefore overwrites them with NaN. Does anyone have any idea, tip, approach how to do this?

I was thinking that I could be selecting every year to then look if it has any NaNs. However I didn't really figure out how to select a year. I tried:

```
 start_date = "01-01"
 end_date = "12-31"

 mask = (df.index.strftime("%H") >= start_date) & (df.index.strftime("%H") <= end_date)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

group by year and set the year to NaN if it contains any NaN values:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Score': [np.NaN, np.NaN, 20.3, 30.9, 14.9, 14.1, 14.8, 14.7, np.NaN]},
                  index=pd.to_datetime(['2005-12-29', '2005-12-30', '2005-12-31', 
                                        '2006-01-02', '2006-01-02', '2006-01-03', 
                                        '2006-12-31', '2007-01-01', '2007-01-02']))

df['Score'] = df.groupby(df.index.year).transform(lambda x: np.nan if x.isnull().values.any() else x)
# df['Score']
# 2005-12-29     NaN
# 2005-12-30     NaN
# 2005-12-31     NaN
# 2006-01-02    30.9
# 2006-01-02    14.9
# 2006-01-03    14.1
# 2006-12-31    14.8
# 2007-01-01     NaN
# 2007-01-02     NaN
```

to fill any month with NaNs that initially contains a NaN, use a `pd.Grouper` with monthly frequency to preserver the year component:

```
df['Score'] = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="M")).transform(lambda x: np.nan if x.isnull().values.any() else x)
```

Comment: Do you know how the same could be achieved with only filling that month with NaN (instead of the whole year)? Considering that df.index.month wouldn't work because of the missing year component.

Comment: @Sanoj: sure, use a Grouper for that, see my edit. Sidenote: you can also use that with freq='Y' instead of `df.index.year`. I just used index.year because I think it is more readable.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) with set missing values (default value) if at least one `NaN` for year tested by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`Series.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html):

```
df['Score'] = df['Score'].mask(df['Score'].isna().groupby(df.index.year).transform('any'))
print (df)
            Score
2005-12-29    NaN
2005-12-30    NaN
2005-12-31    NaN
2006-01-02   30.9
2006-01-02   14.9
2006-01-03   14.1
2006-12-31   14.8
2007-01-01    NaN
2007-01-02    NaN
```

How it working:

```
print (df['Score'].isna())
2005-12-29     True
2005-12-30     True
2005-12-31    False
2006-01-02    False
2006-01-02    False
2006-01-03    False
2006-12-31    False
2007-01-01    False
2007-01-02     True
Name: Score, dtype: bool

print (df['Score'].isna().groupby(df.index.year).transform('any'))
2005-12-29     True
2005-12-30     True
2005-12-31     True
2006-01-02    False
2006-01-02    False
2006-01-03    False
2006-12-31    False
2007-01-01     True
2007-01-02     True
Name: Score, dtype: bool
```